# How to use setted variables in Config.Groovy and concatenate it

Tags: string, grails, config

I want to reuse vars setted once again later in Config.groovy

Example:

```
static.serverURL = "http://static.foo.com"
static.path = ""

bar.default.picUrl=static.serverURL+static.path+"/images/bar.png"
```

but that gives me a

```
groovy.util.ConfigObject.plus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)
```

changing it to

```
bar.default.picUrl=""+static.serverURL+static.path+"/images/bar.png"
```

gives me

```
[:][:]/images/bar.png
```

using

```
bar.default.picUrl=${static.serverURL}+${static.path}+"/images/bar.png"
```

gives me

```
nullnull/images/bar.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
bar.default.picUrl="${static.serverURL}${static.path}"/images/bar.png
```